# Как отключить или не использовать функцию _CorExeMain?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите как отключить использование этой функции?

Может ее вызывает определение разрядности системы `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак.

Эта функция загружает рантайм (CLR) и вызывает функцию `Main`. Без неё ничего работать не будет.

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/corexemain-function

---

Впрочем, можно попытаться [самостоятельно загрузить CLR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/corbindtoruntimeex-function) и запустить код.

Comment: С другой стороны, написано что функцию эту дергает загрузчик, что согласуется с процессом загрузки .NET файлов. Интересно что будет, если убрать ее явный вызов с EP и убрать из импортов :-D

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Скорее всего, программа просто не стартует с криками «вы чё делаете, негодяи?».

Comment: Да вот пишут, что загрузчик ее дернет независимо от точки входа даже... И чистого .NET под рукой нет :-(